# How do I return only the form in the UpdateView class in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to switch form a functional view that edits and submits a form to class based view, UpdateView. I need to access the form.

Until now I use this view:

```
@login_required
def edit_sale_view(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Sale, id=id)
    form = EditSaleForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditSaleForm(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Data saved'})
        else:
           return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Data not saved'})
    return HttpResponse(form.as_p())
```

The `form.as_p()` is important because it is used in the form that is displayed in a modal window.

So, I think that I need to find out how to return only the form and not the whole template.

Answer (score 0):

You can access form instance by overriding `form_valid` method. For example:

```
class SomeView(UpdateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) # or use return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Data saved'})

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(SomeView, self).get_initial()
        # do something
        return initial()
```

Comment: I need to access the form that gets populated with the data from the database before it is edited.

Comment: In that case use get_initial method. I have updated the answer

Comment: I think that instead of finding out how to access the form, I should try to return just the form and not the whole template.